# g++ says I have an undefined reference to a function

Tags: c++, g++

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past while trying to figure this out.  I want to use this function that I got from stack overflow with these function parameters:

```
void split(const string& str, const string& delimiters, vector<string>& tokens);
```

I define it in the header file of my ServerHandler class (ServerHandler.h):

```
public:
   ServerHandler();
   ~ServerHandler();
   void split(const string& str, const string& delimiters, vector<string>& tokens);
   void handleRequest(int client, string request);
   void handlePutRequest(string request);
   bool isValidPutRequest(vector<string> requestTokens);
```

I put it in my ServerHandler.cc class:

```
void split(const string& str, const string& delimiters, vector<string>& tokens)
{
...
}
```

Then I try to call it from my method where I define the two strings and the vector object:

```
vector<string> requestTokens;
...
string firstHalf;
firstHalf = "tell mike hello!";
...
string spaceDelimiter;
spaceDelimiter = " ";
...
split(firstHalf, spaceDelimiter, requestTokens);  // Throws compiler  error here
```

How do I fix this compiler error?

EDIT:

This is the compiler error:

```
ServerHandler.cc:(.text+0x674): undefined reference to `ServerHandler::split(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)'
```

Comment: [This section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/241631) contains the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the class name to the function definition:

```
void ServerHandler::split(const string& str,
                          const string& delimiters,
                          vector<string>& tokens)
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  I'll mark it as correct in 12 minutes.  Gosh, what a total derp on my part.  All of my other methods have ServerHandler:: prepended correctly too.

Comment: @idungotnosn Finding a dupe was faster! You may consider to leave your question, to help others find the more canonical Q&A faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are not declaring the scope of the method in your implementation file:

```
void ServerHandler::split(const string& str, const string& delimiters, vector<string>& tokens)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's not a compiler error though, it's a linker error. The compiler goes fine because you declared the method inside the header file, then during linking phase that method is not resolved.